# Change MKMapView's Zoom - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I using Apple's MapKit and MKMapView to show a location on screen. The function I am using is:

```
func displayLocation() {
    locationMap.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userConnected.siteConnectedLat!, userConnected.siteConnectedLong!), span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)), animated: true)

    let locationPin = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userConnected.siteConnectedLat!, longitude: userConnected.siteConnectedLong!)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = locationPin

    locationMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
    locationMap.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
}
```

Is is then called in the viewDidLoad method of the View Controller. Apple's documentation says that the span should change the zoom but even changing the span is putting minimum effect on the map. I want it to be zoomed out enough so that we can clearly see like 3-4 European countries, i.e, a significant amount of zoom-out.

This is what my map looks like in simulator: 
[image: This is what my map looks like in simulator]

This is how it looks like after I press enlarge:
[image: This is how it looks like after I press enlarge]

Comment: Try a span of (5, 5). Your current span might be too small.

Comment: Not working. Maybe the size of my map is an issue? I've added a map size image in my original question.

Comment: Didi it not do anything at all? Try setting the region in `viewDIdAppear` then.

Comment: Adding it in viewDidAppear works like a charm! Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the region of the map in `viewDidAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`. When `viewDidLoad` is called, the map view has just been loaded - the map hasn't been rendered yet, so you can't set its region.

Another thing to change is the span. (0.05, 0.05) seems too small a span to show 3-4 countries. You should try something bigger, like (5, 5). Remember that these numbers represent in degrees the width and height of the map region.